# How to search a specific record in access with VBA Excel

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

I have searched a bit, but every code i try does not help me to find the answer.

I have this code here:

```vb
   Sub registrar_banco(nome, sobrenome, endereco, email, telefone, celular)

' exporta informações da planilha ativa para uma tabela para uma database no acess

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset, r As Long
'     conecta ao banco de dados access
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
'    string de conexão
    cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\vinyz\Coding\Database11.accdb;"
'     abre o recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open "banco_de_dados", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable
'     abre todos os records da tabela
'    r = 2 ' primeira linha da planilha
'    Do While Len(Range("A" & r).Formula) > 0
'     repeat until first empty cell in column A
        With rs
            .AddNew ' cria um novo record
            .Fields("Nome") = nome
            .Fields("Sobrenome") = sobrenome
            .Fields("Endereco") = endereco
            .Fields("Email") = endereco
            .Fields("Telefone") = telefone
            .Fields("Celular") = telefone
            .Update
        End With
'        r = r + 1 ' next row
'    Loop
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

It add registers to an existing database in Access.
As i'm doing a customer register i'm only using Excel as a bridge for programming and i want to link him with the Access DB.

Right now i'm able to add registers only!

How is it possible to DELETE registers from the DB Access and how is it possible to search a exclusively data in the DB, also how can i bring all the info from Access to Excel.

I was testing this code here but couldn't find a answer of how i can bring a exclusive data or the entire table, also it is presenting me some errors.

I'm new at SQL, trying to learn it, if someone have a step-by-step tutorial of how can i Excel in SQL it will be useful too hahahaha

```vb
Sub buscar_banco()
    Dim cn As Object
Dim rs As Object
Dim strFile As String
Dim strCon As String
Dim strSQL As String
Dim s As String
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

''Access database

strFile = "C:\Users\vinyz\Coding\Database11.accdb"

''This is the Jet 4 connection string, you can get more
''here : http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel

strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\vinyz\Coding\Database11.accdb;"

''Late binding, so no reference is needed

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

cn.Open strCon

'Rough idea
intID = Planilha1.[A1]

strSQL = "SELECT * " _
       & "FROM [banco_de_dados] " _
       & "WHERE ID = " & intID

rs.Open strSQL, cn, 3, 3


''Pick a suitable empty worksheet for the results

Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs

''Tidy up
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: The code would be almost identical to `Find`ing a record directly in Access VBA.  If you do that first and get that working then copy the code to Excel , it will be easier in  the long run.  (Also see [mcve])

Comment: First you need to make sure all your variables are properly declared.. To help find problems, put `Option Explicit` at the top of [every] module [always] and then try running the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a lot of questions for one post. You would be better to post them separately. You will get answers faster.

Meanwhile there are many ways to do the same thing and since I'm working with an older version (2007) here's what I can show you...

To insert, select, update, or delete records you need to learn SQL. Start here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp

You can also use the Access query wizard and design view to learn and copy paste the SQL code into the VBA as you learn more.

Quick samples of alternative SQL statements:

```
"DELETE * FROM Employees WHERE Title = 'Trainee';"

"UPDATE Employees SET ReportsTo = 5 WHERE ReportsTo = 2;"
```

You could bring all records in with the following.

```
"Select * FROM table_name;"
```

Here is also a tutorial of how you can go through the menu (or record a macro) to bring it all in. http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/12/13/

Following is the VBA code I used to select some of the records to bring in matching the cities.

```
Public Sub RunQuery()
    Dim A As Object
    Dim rs As Object
    Dim strSql As String
    Dim strConnection As String
    Set A = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\Northwind 2007.accdb"
    strSql = "SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE City = 'Redmond' OR City = 'Seattle'"
    A.Open strConnection
    Set rs = A.Execute(strSql)
    arr = rs.GetRows

    'now the array arr has the data queried
    ' Write the field names
    For intColIndex = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        Range("A1").Offset(0, intColIndex).Value = rs.Fields(intColIndex).Name
    Next

    firstRow = LBound(arr, 1)
    firstCol = LBound(arr, 2)
    lastRow = UBound(arr, 1)
    lastCol = UBound(arr, 2)

    For i = firstRow To lastRow
      For j = firstCol To lastCol
        Range("A2").Offset(j, i).Value = arr(i, j)
      Next j
    Next i
    ActiveSheet.Columns.AutoFit

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    A.Close
    Set A = Nothing
End Sub
```

Here's one that updates the db:

```
Public Sub RunQueryUpdate()
    Dim A As Object
    Dim rs As Object
    Dim strSql As String
    Dim strConnection As String
    Set A = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\Students.accdb"
    strSql = "UPDATE Students SET Students.Company = 'Testing' WHERE (((Students.[Last Name])='Smith'));"
    A.Open strConnection
    Set rs = A.Execute(strSql)

    Set rs = Nothing
    A.Close
    Set A = Nothing
End Sub
```

Here's Insert:

```
Public Sub RunQueryInsert()
    Dim A As Object
    Dim rs As Object
    Dim strSql As String
    Dim strConnection As String
    Set A = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\Students.accdb"
    strSql = "INSERT INTO Students ([Company], [Last Name], [First Name]) VALUES ('Bay City Fun', 'Smith', 'Jan');"
    A.Open strConnection
    Set rs = A.Execute(strSql)

    Set rs = Nothing
    A.Close
    Set A = Nothing
End Sub
```

Here is the Delete example:

```
Public Sub RunQueryDelete()
    Dim A As Object
    Dim rs As Object
    Dim strSql As String
    Dim strConnection As String
    Set A = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\Students.accdb"
    strSql = "DELETE FROM Students WHERE Company='Howdy';"
    A.Open strConnection
    Set rs = A.Execute(strSql)

    Set rs = Nothing
    A.Close
    Set A = Nothing
End Sub
```